# IE6 UpdatePanel Must move mouse to refresh after async call

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-6, asp.net-3.5

So we are using IE6, and can not migrate to any other browser. So our application is having issues where after we have a postback inside our updatepanel. The browser looks like its resetting the DOM, one select box kind of jumps up a little, but then it freezes for 10-20 seconds, then the page gets updated. Now if we move the mouse it is instantly refreshed everytime. I found

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2000262

but that only moved the time down from 20-30 to 10-20. This only happens our our XP sp3 laptops. Our dev machines run windows 2003 and IE6, and we do not experience the problem. Both machines don't go past 5% CPU usage when the update panel comes back. Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Inside a user control that was inside an update panel there was a link to a ../Site.css, which resolved to localhost/site.css That file did not exist because it was in localhost/web/site.css So when the update panel replaced the innerHTML of the div tag, IE wanted that file, it gave a 404, thus giving the lag that we had.